# SQL Insert and Replace?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have an SQL statement I run for my website that inserts data into an access database. Is there a way during the insert to replace a space " " if one of the date textboxes contains a space? I need to do this because it throws off my date queries if there is a space in one of the columns?

```
INSERT INTO tblOpen (DateColumn1, DateColumn2) Values (@Value1, @Value2)
```

Comment: I need to ask you. Do you store a date value inside a string database field?

Comment: Its just a text data type column

Comment: And here are the roots of your problems. A date should be stored as a date, not as a string. Then you will avoid any kind of problems in querying on that dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the 'datetime' type for your DateColumn. It solves all your problem. It is good to use proper variable for proper field.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean heading and trailing spaces, then:

```
myString = myString.Trim()
```

in your vb.net code will be fine. Even though I would follow Steve's suggestion and converting to date.

Answer (score 1):

As question was about replace, you can either use Replace()

```
INSERT INTO tblOpen (DateColumn1, DateColumn2) 
    Values (REPLACE(@Value1, ' ', ''), @Value2)
```

or LTrim() and RTrim()

```
INSERT INTO tblOpen (DateColumn1, DateColumn2) 
    Values (LTRIM(RTRIM(@Value1)), @Value2)
```

However if datatype is a datetime then it makes sense to convert to that type using

```
DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
SqlParameter p = command.Parameters.Add("@Value1", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
p.Value = d;
```